# Chart application in WPF

Tags: wpf, charts

I want to make a chart application in WPF based on the input data , I dont want to use any of the third party tools. But I want to make it on my own. Can anyone provide me with samples. Thank you

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use 3rd-party tools? Also, you neglected to say what kind of chart you're looking to create (pie chart, bar chart, line chart, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download [the source of the WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and have a look at [the chart controls' source code](http://wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40156#564101).